# Python text into dictionary

Tags: python, text, dictionary

I have the following text in an external file

```
A#
M*
Y%
```

and would like to read it into a dictionary so that it was read as

```
Dictionary = {'A': '#', 'M': '*', 'Y': '%'}
```

I can read the text file if it has a comma in between the letter and the symbol, but cannot do it without. Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Are the two symbols each on a new line, as the edits show?

Comment: @doctorlove Take a look at the original text; it just wasn’t indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just very straight-forward. As you are iterating over each line, you take the first character of each line—that’s the letter—and the second character—that’s the symbol—to fill your dictionary.

```
dictionary = {}
with open('filename') as f:
    for line in f:
        dictionary[line[0]] = line[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I was making alsorts of silly errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s ='''A#                                     
M*
Y%'''
>>> dict(zip(*line)[0] for line in s.splitlines())
{'A': '#', 'Y': '%', 'M': '*'}
```

If you're reading from a file:

```
>>> with open('foo.txt') as f:
    print dict(zip(*line.rstrip())[0] for line in f)
...     
{'A': '#', 'Y': '%', 'M': '*'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a dictionary comprehension.

```
with open('somefile') as file:
    output = {line[0] : line[1] for line in file}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dict(map(str.strip, open("filename")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for:

```
with open('yourfile') as fin:
    mydict = dict(line.rstrip() for line in fin)
```

This relies on the fact that `dict` takes a 2-item to build key/value pairs, and that by removing the trailing whitespace from each line, then we *should* end up with a 2-item.

This has the advantage that it's more *atomic* in that an exception thrown during construction means the `dict` won't remain partially populated, and that you only have to handle a single exception instead of `IndexError`s or others that could be thrown using dict-comps/etc...